# Unable to retrieve a value from the database when the max_quantity field is populated - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm attempting to retrieve the appropriate shopping method data for a specific product when the max_quantity field has a value and the shopping method is active. However, despite saving the data, I'm unable to see the retrieved value in the HTML attribute value. Can I ask for help how to fix the code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name^="shipping_methods"]').on('change', function() {
            var shippingMethodId = $(this).val();
            var shippingValueInput = $('input[name="shipping_methods[' + shippingMethodId + '][max_quantity]"]');

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                shippingValueInput.show();
            } else {
                shippingValueInput.hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach($shippingMethods as $shippingMethod)
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-md-0 mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="shipping_methods[]" id="shipping_method_{{ $shippingMethod->id }}" value="{{ $shippingMethod->id }}"
                                {{ in_array($shippingMethod->id, $product->shippingMethods->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="shipping_method_{{ $shippingMethod->id }}">
                                        {{ $shippingMethod->name }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control shipping-value-input" type="number" name="shipping_methods[{{ $shippingMethod->id }}][max_quantity]" value="{{ $product->shippingMethods->where('id', $shippingMethod->id)->first()->pivot->max_quantity ?? '' }}">
                                <div class="input-group-text">@lang('Max in parcel')</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

and ProductController:

```
        $shippingMethods = $request->input('shipping_methods', []);
    $product->shippingMethods()->detach();

    foreach ($shippingMethods as $shippingMethodId => $data) {
        if (isset($data['max_quantity'])) {
            $maxQuantity = $data['max_quantity'];
            $product->shippingMethods()->attach($shippingMethodId, ['max_quantity' => $maxQuantity]);
        }
    }
```

I attempted multiple times, including connecting via Ajax, but the results remained unchanged. I initially considered model, but eventually decided to give up.